# How can I use GLMM for my data?

Tags: r, experiment-design

So let me tell you a little about my data
I have two columns of transects and plots as random effects
I have an Elevation column as a fixed effect, My response variable is low and high grazing data
###########################################
Six transects of 100 meters were randomly placed in all three sites, with three transects for low grazing (LG) and three for high grazing (HG). Within each transect, 5 plots of 1 × 1 m2 were established at intervals of 20 m, resulting in a total of 90 plots.

I want to check the plots as random effects and the effect of Elevation on the two factors of low and high grazing.
Thank you for your guidance

Comment: *My response variable is low and high grazing data*---Does this mean your outcome is a binary response? I'm not sure what high and low grazing data means here, but it seems to be an odd binary.

Comment: I do not believe that the factor low grazing / high grazing is your actual response variable. From your description "three transects for low grazing (LG) and three for high grazing (HG)" it seems obvious that grazing intensity is an independent variable / predictor.

Comment: Yes, I understand... Plots, transects, and sites are random effects
LG and HG are predictor variables and response variables of plant characteristics and diversity
But when I run it in R, I get an error